# Handling large data with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a large set of data that I need to pull from mysql. Proably would reach 100,000+. I have done optimization for processing the data using indexing and other things. The problem I am facing right now is the memory overflow. Whenever i tried to pull the data higher than 100,000 then it shows memory size error. I have put the memory limit to 512M but there may be chances of large data so I cannot increase the memoery everytime. Is there a better of way of handling this. I am using cakephp and I need all data at once for my system.

Comment: The requirement, that you need all data outside of the database at the same time seems flawed. Maybe you can push some computations to the database and retrieve just a smaller set of data.

Comment: Please define: 'pull from mysql'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a lot of rows in CakePHP & MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095677/returning-a-lot-of-rows-in-cakephp-mysql)

Comment: Also maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865417/working-with-a-large-amount-of-data-from-mysql

Comment: retrieving so many records is perhaps required only if you are synchronizing your whole database with some remote client or redundant server, in such cases you should re-define your synchronization strategy.

Comment: Actually, This is about a market research survey kind of tool and they have an analysis section where they need to take all respondent data to analyze. Since there are many surveys simultaneously running and each survey has lots of response so While analyzing I need to fetch all the response of entire respondents of that survey. This data is then computed to show the analysis in charts and tables. THere are lots of question in survey and and each question may have thousands response so computing this in database is not possible (I tried this :) ).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done using the DB. If you don't think so, the next approach would be a data warehouse -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse

Answer (score 2):

You can't escape the fact that the memory is limited. Period.  The requirement is silly but fine. You'll have to process the data in chunks that fit into the available memory and send the chunks to the client or append them to the file you're writing.

This is basically AJAX pagination or "endless loading" just that you don't change the page but append the next page to the previous in the DOM tree until you reached the last page. Have fun enjoying a probably *very* slow responding site when all records are loaded and millions of elements exist in the DOM tree. ;)

Another way could be to create the view in a background job (shell, cron task) and then just send the pre-generated file to the client like a static page. The shell would have to paginate the data as well and append it to work around the memory limitation.